# Magmi Multistore Product Update

Tags: magento, magmi, multistore

I am Importing product with Magmi In Magento

We have already a Magento store with full products. Now we added a new store in it. now we have two stores on one magento. i want to know how we can implement the both store code in csv and which field as i find field is **_product_websites**. but adding store name with ; or ,

I tried with both but both not working. can someone help me

sku,_product_websites
111,A;B

using this both column

Comment: Can you update your question with a few lines of your csv file with headers used?

Comment: Updated.. I just wanna to know how to update my data and live the product in both store.

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns

Answer (score 1):

You should use following format for import process.

"store","attribute_set","type","sku","websites"

You should use values under **store** header as comma separated like for example: "store1,store2,store3"

*NOTE* :
*From Magmi 0.7.17: "websites" column becomes OBSOLETE*

Please refer following link for more information
[Magmi Import](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Import_new_products)

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns, my csv https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The value that goes in the "store" column should actually be the store view name code, as defined in System->Manage Stores.